# fpdf, how to break lines in python?

Tags: python, fpdf

I am creating several tables in a pdf.
Because of some bugs, I have not been able to write the code with html, so I am only using python.

```
import fpdf
from fpdf import FPDF

def create_table(data, padding):
    # Create instance of FPDF class
    # Letter size paper, use inches as unit of measure
    pdf=FPDF(format='letter', unit='in')
    # Add new page. Without this you cannot create the document.
    pdf.add_page()
    # Remember to always put one of these at least once.
    pdf.set_font('Times','',10.0) 
    # Effective page width, or just epw
    epw = pdf.w - 2*pdf.l_margin
    for table in data:
        # Set column width to 1/4 of effective page width to distribute content 
        # evenly across table and page
        col_width = epw/len(table[1][0])
        # Document title centered, 'B'old, 14 pt
        pdf.set_font('Times','B',14.0) 
        pdf.cell(epw, 0.0, table[0][0], align='C')
        pdf.set_font('Times','',10.0) 
        pdf.ln(0.5)
        th = pdf.font_size
        # Here we add more padding by passing 2*th as height
        for row in table[1]:
            for datum in row:
                # Enter data in colums
                pdf.cell(col_width, padding*th, str(datum), border=1)
            pdf.ln(padding*th)
        # Line break equivalent to 4 lines
        pdf.ln(4*th)

    pdf.output('table-using-cell-borders.pdf','F')


table_1 = [
['table_1'],
#headers
[['A', 'Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccb'],
#values
['a1', 'b1'],
['a2', 'b2'],
]]

table_2 = [
['table_2'],
#headers
[['C', 'D'],
#values
['a1', 'b1'],
['a2', 'b2'],
]]

create_table([table_1, table_2], 3)
```

As you can see, this is the ouptut:
In table_1, the string does not break to the next line,
'\n' is not working as well
[image]

What code can I use to break the string inside of table 1?

Comment: did you try multi-cell?\

Comment: thank you, found the right code. Please put it as an answer so I can give you your +10

Comment: Haha no big deal pal. Glad that you found your answer.